# Kendo UI Mobile - ActionSheet: How To Disable closing AS when click on Background?

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui, uiactionsheet, kendo-mobile

i create an action sheet in KendoUI mobile, but when i click outside(in background) of the action sheet, it dismiss and close. how can i prevent it?
the data-close event is not trigger in this case, i try also to modify some CSS changes but without success.

here is example for kendo ui mobile action sheet with new kendo ui mobile version:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/actionsheet/index

Thanks, 
Chen.R